# Need help in complex postgresql select

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have 3 tables in my database.

One is for activities, another one is for students and the last one is for the student's score in an activity. So one activity can have one or more student's scores, and one student has one score in one activity.

So I need to show a list of activities of student's course even if he has not score yet. But, if the student has a score in some activity, I must only show that student's score.

My problem is that when I select the student's score, I need to add a 'where' condition to select only his scores, but if he has not score yet, I have no records in my results. How can I select all activities of a course and only if the student has score, then select only his score for that activity?

Activity Table:

```
id | name        | score
1  | first exam  | 30
2  | second exam | 30
3  | final exam  | 40
```

Student Table:

```
id | name
1  | Jhon
2  | Sam
3  | Frank
```

Student's Score Table:

```
id | activity | student | score
1  | 1        | 1       | 16
2  | 1        | 2       | 17
3  | 1        | 3       | 15
```

So, if Jhon enter to the system and want to see activities's course, he should see a list of all activities but only his score. For example this list:

```
Activity    | Score | Your Score
First Exam  | 30    | 16
Second Exam | 30    | -
Final Exam  | 40    | -
```

Comment: It would be nice to have your table structure (and maybe some data)

Comment: Also what you've tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a left outer join:

```
select a.activity_id, coalesce(acs.score, 0) as thescore
from activities a left outer join
     activityscores acs
     on a.activity_id = acs.activity_id and
        acs.student_id = THESTUDENTID;
```

If a student can have more than one score in an activity, then you would want an aggregation as well.